# Xamarin Forms ListView ViewCell translation

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, resources, translation

I have 2 Resources file for translation in my project. I'm using the parameters in my layouts and it working fine but I have a `ListView` that I need to bind a parameter to it from this resource file!

[image: Resources]

```
  <Label Text="Quantity" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#231F20" FontFamily="{StaticResource MyriadProRegularFont}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <Label.FontSize>
                    <OnIdiom Phone="12" Tablet="14"/>
            </Label.FontSize>
   </Label>
```

This label is placed in a `ListView` and I need to bind it to a parameter in the resource file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting "Access Modifier" into public in the Resource file

[image: access modifier]

And binding the label to the parameter:

```
 <Label Text="{x:Static controls2:LanguageResource.quantity}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#231F20" FontFamily="{StaticResource MyriadProRegularFont}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                                        <OnIdiom Phone="12" Tablet="14"/>
                                                    </Label.FontSize>
                                                </Label>
```

And this xmlns is placed in the top of the XAML file

```
 xmlns:controls2="clr-namespace:AppXamarin.Resources"
```